# Parse an expression to chunk labels

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to pass an expression to a YAML chunk label in Quarto using R. I know how to do this for knitr chunk options in R Markdown (and I also know that this works well in Quarto). However, I would like to know if this is possible using the current labeling idiom.

For example, with the following source...

[image]

...I can generate some output that has figure captions as well as cross-references.

[image]

To be clear, using the normal chunk options, I want to use the second chunk like this:

````
```{r}
#| label: fig-plot-cars
#| fig-cap = <cap>
#| echo: false
plot(cars)  
```
````

where `<cap>` is the variable created earlier (or any expression) that returns a string for the figure caption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `!expr` in your `fig-cap:` to parse an R expression like this:

````
---
title: ""
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: caption
#| include: false
cap <- 'Displacement vs Speed'
```

See @fig-plot-cars.

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot-cars
#| fig-cap: !expr cap
#| echo: false
plot(cars)  
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but note that in your version you still have the traditional chunk option `fig.cap`.