# Parse an expression with cross reference to chunk options

Tags: r, pdf, quarto

This question is an extension of [an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74402963/quarto-parsing-an-expression-to-chunk-labels)

In my case, the expression contains a cross-reference to an other table that I would like to see rendered, but I can't find out how.

**Note:** I just found that the approach below does work when outputting to html, but not for pdf.

MWE:

````
```{r}

tab <- data.frame(A = "A")
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-tab1
#| tbl-cap: cap 1

kableExtra::kable(tab)
```

```{r}
cap <- "This table is identical to @tbl-tab1"
```


```{r}
#| label: tbl-tab2
#| tbl-cap: !expr cap

kableExtra::kable(tab)
```

While I can reference @tbl-tab1 outside a caption.
````

Below the output I get (to pdf), where the red box indicates the cross reference not working (instead of `@tbl-tab1` it should state `Table 1`, just as it does in the sentence *While I can reference Table 1 outside a caption*)

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what your expected outcome is?

Comment: As the above comment gets some likes: the expected outcome is explained in the Q. I want caption 2 to read 'This table is identical to Table 1' rather than the current 'This table is identical to @tbl-tab1' when I output to pdf

Answer (score 1):

You do that using the paste function in R. instead of putting the string in quotes, use: `paste("this table is identical to",@tbl-tab1)` and see if it gives you the expected output.

Comment: It doesn't. Unquoted - as you put it - it results in an error. If I quote the @tbl -part, it is identical to my MWE output